# scheme read function's behavior

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, guile

I can't understand this scheme `read` function's behavior.

```
gosh> (null? '())
#t
gosh> (null? (read))
'()
#f
gosh> (define a (read))
'()
a
gosh> a
'()
gosh> (null? a)
#f
```

I expected `(null? (read))` is `#t`(true) when I inputted `'()`. Not only Gauche, but also MIT-Scheme and GNU/Guile behaves like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` function doesn't evaluate the text its given, it treats it as an *unevaluated expression* and returns the expression tree as data. For example:

```
(read)  ;input: (+ 4 5)
```

Is equivalent to `(list '+ 4 5)`:

```
> (read)  ;input: (+ 4 5)
(+ 4 5)
> (list '+ 4 5)
(+ 4 5)
> (equal? (read) (list '+ 4 5))  ;input: (+ 4 5)
#t
```

From now on I'll use the `;=` syntax to demonstrate how you would write it with constructors like `list`.

```
> (read)  ;input: (+ 4 5)
;= (list '+ 4 5)
(+ 4 5)
```

Now, because `read` returns the data representation for the expression its given, it "adds a quote level". By that I mean that to write an equivalent expression, you would have to wrap `quote` around it.

```
> (read)  ;input: (+ 4 5)
;= (list '+ 4 5)
;= '(+ 4 5)
> (read)  ;input: (quote (+ 4 5))
;= (list 'quote (list '+ 4 5))
;= '(quote (+ 4 5))
;= ''(+ 4 5)
```

Because `read` and `write` deal with *unevaluated expressions*, the `read` function will seem to add a quote level, and the `write` function will seem to remove a quote level:

```
> (write '(+ 4 5))
;output: (+ 4 5)
> (write ''(+ 4 5))
;output: '(+ 4 5)
> (write '''''(+ 4 5))
;output: ''''(+ 4 5)
```

The `read` function does the opposite, seeming to add a quote level. However, this is made more obscure by the fact that the Scheme Repl uses `write`, which "removes" it again. However, if you concentrate on the `;=` expressions it's more clear why `read` and `write` are opposites:

```
> (read)  ;input (+ 4 5)                  (no quotes)
;= '(+ 4 5)                               (one quote)
(+ 4 5)                                   (the `write` function removes a quote)
> (read)  ;input '(+ 4 5)                 (one quote)
;= ''(+ 4 5)                              (two quotes)
'(+ 4 5)                                  (the `write` function removes a quote)
> (read)  ;input '''(+ 4 5)               (three quotes)
;= ''''(+ 4 5)                            (four quotes)
'''(+ 4 5)                                (the `write` function removes a quote)
```

Now back to your example:

```
> (read)  ;input: '()
;= ???
???
```

Since `read` adds a quote to represent an expression as data, reading `'()` is equivalent to `''()`.

```
> (read)  ;input: '()
;= ''()
;= (list 'quote (list))
'()
> (define a (read))  ;input: '()
> a
;= ''()
;= (list 'quote (list))
'()
> (equal? a ''())
#t
> (equal? a (list 'quote (list)))
#t
```

To actually get something equivalent to `'()` so that it will be `null?`, you have to give `()` as input.

```
> (read)  ;input: ()
;= '()
;= (list)
()
> (define a (read))  ;input: ()
> a
;= '()
;= (list)
()
> (equal? a '())
#t
> (null? a)
#t
```